# NuGet lock file fails to restore with --locked-mode

Tags: .net, build, msbuild, nuget, binary-reproducibility

Roslyn gave us [`deterministic` builds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/deterministic-compiler-option) a few years ago.

And with the addition of [**NuGet lock files**](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/enable-repeatable-package-restores-using-a-lock-file/), we can finally have guaranteed **reproducible build**.

I'm [looking at the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#lock-file-extensibility) that say I can opt-in with

`--use-lock-file Bootstraps use of lock file for a project. You can alternatively set RestorePackagesWithLockFile property in the project file`

And will require a lock file when restoring with:

`--locked-mode Enables locked mode for restore. This is useful in CI/CD scenarios where you would like to get the repeatable builds. This can be also by setting the RestoreLockedMode MSBuild property to true`

I'm trying it out by modifying the `Directory.Build.props` at the root of the repo:

```xml
   <PropertyGroup>
     ...
+    <RestorePackagesWithLockFile>true</RestorePackagesWithLockFile>
   </PropertyGroup>
```

When I run `dotnet restore`, I see the `lock` files generated:

```
    benchmarks/Sentry.Benchmarks/packages.lock.json
    samples/Sentry.Samples.AspNetCore.Basic/packages.lock.json
    ...
    test/Sentry.Tests/packages.lock.json
```

Now if I try to restore: `dotnet restore --locked-mode`, it fails completely. A summary of the output is:

```
/Users/bruno/git/sentry-dotnet/test/Sentry.Tests/Sentry.Tests.csproj : error NU1603: System.Private.DataContractSerialization 4.1.1 depends on System.Xml.XmlDocument (>= 4.0.1) but System.Xml.XmlDocument 4.0.1 was not found. An approximate best match of System.Xml.XmlDocument 4.3.0 was resolved. [/Users/bruno/git/sentry-dotnet/Sentry.sln]
/Users/bruno/git/sentry-dotnet/test/Sentry.Tests/Sentry.Tests.csproj : error NU1603: System.Xml.XPath.XmlDocument 4.0.1 depends on System.Xml.XmlDocument (>= 4.0.1) but System.Xml.XmlDocument 4.0.1 was not found. An approximate best match of System.Xml.XmlDocument 4.3.0 was resolved. [/Users/bruno/git/sentry-dotnet/Sentry.sln]
  Restore failed in 383.47 ms for /Users/bruno/git/sentry-dotnet/test/Sentry.NLog.Tests/Sentry.NLog.Tests.csproj.
  Restore failed in 370.7 ms for /Users/bruno/git/sentry-dotnet/test/Sentry.Testing/Sentry.Testing.csproj.
```

I must be getting something totally wrong here.

PS: I've pushed the changes to a branch and [opened a PR on GitHub](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/pull/247/files) if one is interested to taking a look.

EDIT: Jan 2021: 1 and half year later I tried again with the .NET 5 SDK, and I still have problems:
https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/pull/731

I've tried `DisableImplicitNuGetFallbackFolder` without success. The lock file seem to be platform dependant.

In CI it works properly on `macOS` and `Linux` but fails on `Windows`. I created the lock file on a Mac. I pulled the branch on Windows and it indeed fails with:

```
error NU1403: Package content hash validation failed for System.Net.Http.4.3.0. The package is different than the last restore.
```

I'd bet money it's using the file path separator such as `/` when calculating the hash and that's the reason for the failure.

Comment: Hi, any updates on this? I am having exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

Cross-platform stable lock-files should be possible by adding `RuntimeIdentifiers` to your `PropertyGroup`, e.g. `<RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x64;linux-x64;osx-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>`

Comment: This definitely worked for me. Every time I would cross compile before, my locks would change. Now they have entries for each `RuntimeIdentifier`. Thanks!